# jQuery PHP foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<? foreach($words as $word): ?>
<li>
    <form action="javascript:alert( 'success!' );">
      <div>
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
      </div>
    </form>
</li>
<? endforeach; ?>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    if ( $( "input:first" ).val() === "<?php $word['Word']['words'] ?>" ) {
        $( spans ).text( "Validated..." ).show();
         return;
      }})
  });
</script>
```

This script should compare every words from input to the 'words' (table in MySQL), but when I write something in input and press submit - they are working all submit.
How to create a unique form and an input for each word into that form?

Comment: You should read up on basic javascript, and especially the `this` keyword.

Comment: Does php's `foreach()` not take curly braces `{...}`?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 you can use either `foreach () { ... }` or `foreach(): ... endforeach;` in PHP. The latter is often used in templates where most of the code is HTML markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think any of the examples here would work, because none actually compares the input value to the word of the foreach loop. Try this:

```
<? foreach($words as $word): ?>
<li>
  <form data-word="<? echo $word; ?>">
    <div>
      <span class="validation"></span>
      <input class="word" type="text">
      <input type="submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</li>
<? endforeach; ?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this),
      value = $form.find('.word').val(),
      word = $form.data('word'),
      valid = word === value,
      message = valid ? 'Validated...' : 'Not valid.';

    $form
      .find('.validation')
      .html(message)
      .show();

    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be improved:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        // add a context where we should find `input:first`
        if ( $( this ).find( "input:first" ).val() === "<?php $word['Word']['words'] ?>" ) {  
             $( spans ).text( "Validated..." ).show();
             return;
    }})
});
```

And also you should `echo` php-value here:

```
"<?php echo $word['Word']['words'] ?>"
```

otherwise it will be just `""`